# SQL_NEED_DATA returned on simple integer

Tags: sql-server, parameters, query-string

I modified one of my queries adding the 3rd parameter of type `int` and now trying to bind the integer value to it. The call is as follows:

```
ret = SQLBindParameter( stmt_tableProp, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &tableId, 0, &cbId );
```

The value of the `tableId` is `171147655`.

After adding this function the call to SQLExecute() starts returning SQL_NEED_DATA.

In the table the column is of the type `integer`.

I don't understand this - I am not passing big data to the query and I am not using BLOB.

Why am I getting the SQL_NEED_DATA?

If I take the 3 parameter out everything works again.

Comment: So is SQLBindParameter returning the error or, if the eror happens when you execute the query, did SQLBindParameter return an error?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, SQLBindParameter executes successfully. It is SQLExecute() which gives SQL_NEED_DATA.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour occurs if the last parameter of the [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function) function (`StrLen_or_IndPtr`) is set to `SQL_DATA_AT_EXEC`.

You should check the value of your `cbId` variable.

**The error also seems to occur if you do not initialize the provided variable.**